# Force LaTeX to obey spaces in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, catcodes

I have experienced a very frustrating feature of LaTeX.

I have used `bnf.tex` to be able to write a BNF grammar definition. As I found the notation `<some text>` very convenient, I decided to use it through the entire document. This might be a bad idea, but now I would rather not change the whole source.

Here are my macros:

```
{\catcode`\ =\active{\global\let =\ }}
\gdef<{\ensuremath{\langle}%
   \ifmmode\catcode`\ =\active\relax\fi%
   \begingroup\sf}
\gdef>{\/\endgroup\ensuremath{\rangle}%
   \ifmmode\catcode`\ =10\relax\fi%
   \relax}
```

It works very well, except when argument to complex math commands.

So

```
<cou cou>
$<cou cou>$
and $\sqrt{<cou cou>}$
```

will keep their inner space, but

```
$$\frac{<cou cou>}{E}$$
and $\Instr{<cou cou>}{E}$
```

will lose their's, looking like `<coucou>`.

In fact, any solution formatting the text between `<` and `>` as normal (`\sf`) text in both math and normal mode would be very useful here :-)

Here is a full file containing the examples:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\instr}{Instr}
\newcommand{\Instr}[2]{\instr(#1,#2)}

\catcode`\>\active
\catcode`\<\active

{\catcode`\ =\active{\global\let =\ }}

\begingroup

    \gdef<{\ensuremath{\langle}%
        \ifmmode\catcode`\ =\active\relax\fi%
        \begingroup\sf}
    \gdef>{\/\endgroup\ensuremath{\rangle}%
        \ifmmode\catcode`\ =10\relax\fi%
        \relax}

\endgroup

\begin{document}

<cou cou>

$<cou cou>$

$$\frac{<cou cou>}{E}$$

$\Instr{<cou cou>}{E}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would simplify the definition to this one:

```
\catcode`\<\active
\protected\def<#1>{\ensuremath{\langle\text{\normalfont\sffamily #1\/}\rangle}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\instr}{Instr}

\catcode`\<\active
\protected\def<#1>{\ensuremath{\langle\text{\normalfont\sffamily#1\/}\rangle}}

\begin{document}

<cou cou>

$<cou cou>\frac{<cou cou>}{2}$

\[\frac{<cou cou>}{E}\]

$\instr(<cou cou>,E)$

\end{document}
```

I don't see any advantage in using an `\Instr` command that hides the semantics. Never use `$$...$$` in LaTeX. Also consider that two-letter commands such as `\sf` are obsolete and should not be used: it's best to stick with the LaTeX2e commands `\sffamily` and similar ones that suggest more clearly what font attribute we are selecting; `\normalfont` is used to avoid that the surrounding font can influence the typesetting of the syntactic object.

However, instead of activating `<`, I suggest you

```
\protected\def\<#1>{\ensuremath{\langle\text{\normalfont\sffamily#1\/}\rangle}}
```

and then to input the thing as

```
\<cou cou>
```

Comment: this is very interresting. Why does it work ? I never saw such a definition embedding the ending character.
This looks like pattern matching ;-)

Comment: @Layus This is an example of a *delimited argument* (for which it's necessary to use `\def`, as `\newcommand` won't accept it. More information in the TeXbook or in TeX by Topic (`texdoc texbytopic`).

Answer (score 6):

Generally it's a bad idea to change catcodes mid document, just use a box to switch to text mode (with an extra group in case you ever use color)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\instr}{Instr}
\newcommand{\Instr}[2]{\instr(#1,#2)}

\catcode`\>\active
\catcode`\<\active


\begingroup

    \gdef<{\ensuremath{\langle}\hbox\bgroup\bgroup\sffamily}
    \gdef>{\/\egroup\egroup\ensuremath{\rangle}}

\endgroup

\begin{document}

<cou cou>

$<cou cou>$

$$\frac{<cou cou>}{E}$$

$\Instr{<cou cou>}{E}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would have sweared that i tried this...

Thank you anyway !

Comment: Can you please expand on your comment about colour? I always thought that the double group enclosure was to protect from `\aftergroup` used by NFSS and helps not to allow font changes to leak out.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides it is `\aftergroup` but the real problem cases are colour commands, specifically colour commands in boxes, where the colour restore is positioned by `\aftergroup` but needs to stay in the box. The kernel uses `\color@endbox` and friends which do nothing unless `color` is loaded, but that was just to increase compatibility with LaTeX2.09 packages a long while ago, may as well just use two groups directly in new stuff.

Comment: @Layus I was going to mention that `\hbox` doesn't get smaller in subscripts so if you need that you should use the ams packages and `\text` (which would also take care of colour support) but @egreg already replied with that so you might want to go with his.

Comment: I never though that i might need to use it in a subscript... but it happened.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The catcode changes are global. Please why then do you put the definitions in a local group?

Comment: @AhmedMusa no reason, It was that way in the original MWE, and I just edited that to make it work. The local catcode change that I mentioned in my answer was the change to the space catcode in the original code which I removed from my version.